# windows7, the headphone device in playback option is gone after I chose don't use this device (don't enable), can't find how to get it back

Tags: windows-7, audio

[image]

I just curious and click on disable and now the icon is gone, I don't know how to bring it back

Answer (score 0):

**To enable a disabled device under a Sound menu in Windows:**

Press Right Mouse Button:

[image]

and choose "Show Disable Devices".
After that choose a device you would like to enable.
Right Mouse Button on this device and choose "Enable".

[image]

Your problem should be solved by now.

Comment: unfortunately, I tried this and it gave no result

Comment: It may need to be reenabled in the Device Manager.